# Need Help With My Trigger to Update OpportunityLineItem

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem

I have a problem with my update trigger. I created Order and Order Line Item custom objects, same and related with Opportunity and Opportunity Line Item. When I create an Order, a related Opportunity also created automatically. Their relations are:

- Lookup on Order to Opportunity (Opportunities__c)
- Lookup on Opportunity to Order (Orders__c)
- Lookup on Order Line Item to Order (Order__c)
- Lookup on Order Line Item to Product2 (Product2__c)
- Lookup on Product2 to Order Line Item (Order_Line_Items__c)

When I update a product on Order Line Item, that product doesn't get updated on related Opportunity Line Item. This trigger doesn't update anything but I'm not getting any error. Do you have any idea what am I missing?

```
trigger OrderLineTrigger on Order_Line_Item__c (after update) {
  if(trigger.isUpdate){

    List<ID> orderlistid= new List<ID>();
    List<ID> pricebooklistid= new List <ID>();
    List<Order_Line_Item__c> updatelist=trigger.new;

    for(Order_Line_Item__c updatelists:updatelist){
      orderlistid.add(updatelists.Order__c);
      pricebooklistid.add(updatelists.Product2__c);
    }  

    List<Opportunity> opportunitylist=new list<Opportunity>([Select Id,Orders__c From Opportunity Where Orders__c IN:orderlistid]);  
    List<PricebookEntry> pricebookentrylist=new List<PricebookEntry>([Select Id,Product2Id From PricebookEntry Where Product2Id IN:pricebooklistid]);
    List<ID> opportunityid=new List<ID>();
    List<ID> pbeid=new List<ID>();

    for(Integer k=0;k<opportunitylist.size();k++){
      opportunityid.add(opportunitylist[k].Id);
    }

    for(Integer l=0;l<pricebookentrylist.size();l++){
      pbeid.add(pricebookentrylist[l].Product2Id);
    }

    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLists=new List<OpportunityLineItem>([Select UnitPrice, Quantity, PricebookEntryId, OpportunityId, Id From OpportunityLineItem Where PricebookEntryId IN:pbeid AND OpportunityId In:opportunityid]); 

    for(Integer i=0;i<oppLists.size();i++){

      for(Integer j=0;j<opportunitylist.size();j++){

        if(oppLists[i].OpportunityId==opportunitylist[j].Id){

          for(Integer n=0;n<pricebookentrylist.size();n++){

            if(oppLists[i].PriceBookEntryId==pricebookentrylist[n].Id){

              for(Integer l=0;l<updatelist.size();l++){

                if(updatelist[l].Order__c==opportunitylist[j].Orders__c && updatelist[l].Product2__c==pricebookentrylist[n].Product2Id ){

                  oppLists[i].UnitPrice=updatelist[l].UnitPrice__c;
                  oppLists[i].Quantity=updatelist[l].Quantity__c;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }    
    update oppLists;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you update `oppLists<OpportunityLineItem>` in your trigger, that's all you're updating. If you want anything else to update, you need to specifically update that related object as well. Otherwise, you won't see anything happen unless it triggers workflow. Try updating the opportunities they're a part of afterward to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yes this trigger for when I update Order Line Item product manually, updating same product in related Opportunity Line Item automatically.